# How to print Stringbuffer content in textarea or on jsp?

Tags: jsp

The code in setvlet:

request.setAttribute("data", sb);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/viewLogs.jsp").forward(request, response);
here sb is string buffer.
when i use to print sb on console its printing perfectly.but when tried to print the same in viewLogs.jsp Iam using

${data}
 It is not printing properly(String buffer having XML data also.No tags are printing on jsp page).But the same string buffer is printing perfectly on console.
Please suggest me how can i show the string buffer content properly to user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's successfully printed. Do rightclick and *View Source*. It's all in there! It's only not recognizable as valid HTML, so the browser just ignores it during presentation.

If your intent is to display XML content as plain text, then you should XML-escape characters which would otherwise be interpreted as HTML, like `<` and `>` indicating start and end of HTML tags.

The canonical solution is to use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:out>` for that.

```
<c:out value="${data}" />
```

If you would like to preserve formatting (whitespace and such), then put it in `<pre>`.

```
<pre><c:out value="${data}" /></pre>
```

Or, apply CSS `white-space:pre` on the parent element.

```
<div class="preformatted"><c:out value="${data}" /></div>
```

with

```
.preformatted {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: You're so unhelpful in helping us to understand your concrete 
problem. Please elaborate "not printing properly" in developer's terms instead of in enduser's terms. What exactly do you see when you do rightclick and *View Source* as hinted in the answer? What exactly do you see in the both sides when you use `<c:out>` instead? Perhaps it still appears unparsed in the generated HTML source and thus you just forgot to install/declare JSTL?

Comment: Hi Balu Sory .. When i rightclick and see view source.I can be able to see proper response when i add (<c:out value="${data}" />)in JSP page. its not showing properly to the user(For eg line alignment and no xml tags).I need exact output on JSP page which i can see when i click on viewsource.

Comment: So, you want to preserve the formatting? Just put it in HTML `<pre>` element, or apply CSS `white-space: pre` on the parent HTML element.

Comment: i want the content which is in value="${data}" on JSP page as it is.I could see perfectly when i view source but not getting on JSP page.

Comment: As said ... Just put it in HTML `<pre>` element, or apply CSS `white-space: pre` on the parent HTML element. Or are you completely new to HTML/CSS as well and not understanding what I said?

Comment: thank you...but some problem when i use  <pre><c:out value="${data}" /></pre> this its preserving spaces and all but not printing xml tags.

Comment: Iam getting Part Content:

 
    
        JFKJ1BA
    
    
        SINVPSQ
    
    QU

instead of                                                                   Part Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <TypeBHeader>
    <Destination>
        <Address>JFKJ1BA</Address>
    </Destination>
    <Origin>
        <Address>SINVPSQ</Address>
    </Origin>
    <PriorityCode>QU</PriorityCode>
</TypeBHeader>

Comment: That's the output as you would get when not using `<c:out>`. So, either JSTL isn't installed/declared properly (click the "JSTL" link in my answer to learn how to do that), or you're not running the code you think you're running.

Answer (score 0):

Printing in JSP:

`<% out.append( sb.toString() ); %>`

But first you must tranform what is inside sb into correct HTML:

- ">" becomes "&gt";
- "<" becomes "&lt";

  ...

Comment: but there is no sb in jsp.could you please elaborate what i need to do ?